# Set field in struct by reference

Tags: pointers, go, struct

I want to set the `Request` struct field `Response` by reference in the function `request` in order to use it further below in the main function. Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
{Status: StatusCode:0 Proto: ProtoMajor:0 ProtoMinor:0 Header:map[] Body:<nil> ContentLength:0 TransferEncoding:[] Close:false Uncompressed:false Trailer:map[] Request:<nil> TLS:<nil>}
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x18 pc=0x4922d1]

goroutine 1 [running]:
io.copyBuffer(0x72dbc0, 0xc0000a8008, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc000196000, 0x8000, 0x8000, 0xb9, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/lib/go/src/io/io.go:402 +0x101
io.Copy(...)
    /usr/lib/go/src/io/io.go:364
main.main()
    /home/y/code/scmc/foo.go:49 +0x20d
exit status 2
```

The code looks as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

type Request struct {
    Method   string
    Url      string
    Reader   io.Reader
    Response *http.Response
}

func request(r Request) error {
    request, err := http.NewRequest(r.Method, r.Url, r.Reader)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    client := &http.Client{}
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if r.Response != nil {
        r.Response = response
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    var r http.Response

    if err := request(Request{
        Method:   "GET",
        Url:      "http://google.com",
        Response: &r,
    }); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", r)

    if _, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, r.Body); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `func request(r Request)` passes a copy of the `Request` struct to the function. `r.Response` is then set on this temporary instance. Also, setting a value of a parent struct's field to a different value cannot possibly affect the value of your local variable.

Comment: Semantically though I wouldn't make`Response` to be a member of `Request`. You should have a readonly `Request` struct, and return a new `Response` instance separately.

Comment: As an alternative to @icza's answer you can keep the field `Response *http.Response`, allocate the `r` variable as a pointer, i.e. `var r = new(http.Response)`, then set the Request's field simply as `Response: r,`, and then to set the response inside the `request` function you'd do `*r.Response = *response`. Now when `request` exits the `r` variable will point to the response returned by the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`client.Do()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Do) returns a pointer: [`*http.Response`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response). If you want to "transfer" a `*http.Response` pointer value out of your function, you need a pointer value to this type which you may set. That pointer value has to be of type `**http.Response` (note: pointer to pointer):

```
type Request struct {
    Method   string
    Url      string
    Reader   io.Reader
    Response **http.Response
}
```

Inside your `request()` function you need to set the *pointed* value:

```
if r.Response != nil {
    *r.Response = response
}
```

And when calling `request()`:

```
var r *http.Response

if err := request(Request{
    Method:   "GET",
    Url:      "http://google.com",
    Response: &r,
}); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

**For analogy:**

If you'd want to transfer out an `int` value:

```
func do(i *int) {
    *i= 10
}

// Calling it:
var i int
do(&i)
```

To transfer out an `*int` value:

```
func do(i **int) {
    x := 10
    *i = &x
}

// Calling it:
var i *int
do(&i)
```